# Visitor visa entering expiry period

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada

I received a Canadian visa multiple entry, valid for 5 years. Is there a time when you must first enter Canada ? Specifically, if you first enter Canada after 2 years since I got the visa ?

Comment: Are you asking if you can still use your visa or if you must use the visa before it expires ?

Comment: Iam asking if I can still use my visa.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your visa is still valid, you are allowed to travel to Canada and request entry (note that a visa doesn't *allow* you to enter, merely that you can arrive). Also note that you must [travel](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=442&t=16) by the date on your visa, it's the last day by which you can enter.

Once you arrive, it's up to the immigration official to determine whether or not they'll let you in as the final decision always lays with them. They might ask you about why you didn't visit when your visa was granted, just be truthful. Everything else being equal you should have no trouble.